# What algorithm can I use to show what columns an element was contained in?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's say we have a list of lists like this:

> [[John, Charles], [Alex, Amy], [Charles, Jacob, Amy]]

Is there an algorithm that I can use that shows what number list an element was in so that it looks like this?

> [John: [0], Charles: [0,2], Amy: [1,2], Alex: [1], Jacob: [2]]

I'm pretty sure there is an easy algorithm for this on the internet, but I can't really put what I'm asking into words that are easily Google-able.

Comment: You can use a hash table. Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @taha I'll look into that, thank you very much!

Comment: do you have programming language preference?

Answer (score 0):

Some Python:

```
In [8]: from collections import defaultdict

In [9]: data  = [['John', 'Charles'], ['Alex', 'Amy'], ['Charles', 'Jacob', 'Amy']]

In [10]: accumulator = defaultdict(list)

In [11]: for index, names in enumerate(data):
    ...:     for name in names:
    ...:         accumulator[name].append(index)

In [12]: answer = dict(accumulator)

In [13]: answer
Out[13]: {'John': [0], 'Charles': [0, 2], 'Alex': [1], 'Amy': [1, 2], 'Jacob': [2]}

In [14]:
```